# jquery Validate errorPlacement insert element + br + error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, errorplacement

I'm trying to use 'errorPlacement' from jQuery Validation DOCS, like that:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

So far so good, but what I really want is to insert a **<br />** tag between the input and the error label in each case:

```
<input>
**<br />**
<label class="error">
```

I have tried with:

```
error.insertAfter(element.append($('<br />'));
```

...but no luck. Is there a simple way of doing it? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't need to do that.

Just use [the `errorElement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorelement) to change the default error element from `label` (inline) to `div` (block), so that it automatically wraps to the next line.

```
$("#myform").validate({
    errorElement: "div", // default is 'label'
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

---

Otherwise, your code...

```
error.insertAfter(element.append($('<br />'));
```

- is missing a closing parentheses, `)`
- is not the correct format... you do not put a string to append within a jQuery selector, `$()`

Would be...

```
error.insertAfter(element.append('<br />'));
```

However, that still does not work as intended because [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is trying to put the content *inside* of `element`.

---

**This way works as you requested...**

```
$("#myform").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.after(error).after('<br/>');
    }
});
```

**DEMO:   http://jsfiddle.net/1pfvug7r/**

Comment: Thanks, but I need the errorElement to be the "label" because I want to validate some other inputs with that inline behaviour...

Comment: Thanks @Sparky, I have tried the last approach, and it seems to work when I append some random text, i.e. `error.insertAfter(element.append('random'));`. However, when I put some HTML tag inside, nothing is appended... :(

Comment: @andcl85, I don't think `append()` is the proper approach here as it puts content _inside_ of the target. See:  http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
        $('<br/>').insertAfter(element);
    }
});
```

But you can use css:

```
input, 
label.error {float:left;clear:both;}
```